# For $a,b \in S$ show that $a^{n(a)+1}=a$ and $a^{n(a)}=b^{n(b)}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

I have the following question:

> Let $S$ be a semigroup with finite number of elements. Suppose that the two cancellation laws hold in $S$; that is, if either $ab = ac$ or $ba = ca$, then $b = c$. Firstly, show that for each $a \in S$ there exist a positive integer $n(a)$ such that $a^{n(a)+1}=a$. Also show that if $a,b \in S$, then $a^{n(a)}=b^{n(b)}$.

I attempted the first part by using the definition of the order of $a$, "$o(a)=n$", where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and then letting $n=n(a)$, I used $a^n=e$, where $e$ is the identity element. Then multiplied with $a$ on the right. But I realised this is not correct because $S$ is only a semigroup.

The second part I did similarly, with $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, where $n(a)=n$ and $m=n(b)$ to end up with $a^n=e=a^m$, but this is obviously then also not correct.

How can I show the first and second part by using the finiteness and cancellation laws?

Comment: Under these conditions, you can actually prove that if $S$ is nonempty, then it is a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part, suppose that there was no such positive integer $n(a)$ then $a^n\neq a^m$ for any positive integers $n\neq m$ (else, assuming $n>m$ we could use cancellation to obtain $a^{n-m+1} = a$). This would contradict the fact that $S$ has a finite number of elements. For the second part
$$a\cdot a^{n(a)} = a\implies a\cdot a^{n(a)}\cdot b = a\cdot b = a\cdot b^{n(b)}\cdot b$$. Then using left and right cancellation we obtain $a^{n(a)} = b^{n(b)}$.

Comment: Could you please explain the part about -- else, assuming $n>m$ we could use cancellation to obtain $a^{n-m+1} = a$? How do we get to $a^{n-m+1} = a$?

Comment: If $n > m$ and $a^n = a^m$ then $a^{n-(m-1)}\cdot a^{m-1} = a\cdot a^{m-1}$. Now cancel $a^{m-1}$ on both sides.

Comment: Thank you. At the second part on the left, does $a \cdot a^{n(a)} = a$ follow from $a^{n(a)+1}=a \implies a^{1+n(a)}=a$?

Comment: Yes, in general $a^m\cdot a^n = a^n\cdot a^m$ for any positive integers $m$ and $n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/245965/karthik-kannan: Sorry to bother you again. How does $n>m$ and $a^n=a^m$ imply $a^{n-(m-1)}\cdot a^{m-1} = a\cdot a^{m-1}$? Is this some type of known fact? Also: If $a^n\neq a^m$ for any positive integers $n \neq m$, how does this contradict the fact that $S$ has a finite number of elements?

Comment: I used the fact that $a^{x+y} = a^{x}\cdot a^{y}$ for positive integers $x$ and $y$.