# If $n>m$ and $a^n=a^m$ for any $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a^{n-(m-1)}\cdot a^{m-1} = a\cdot a^{m-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Please bear with me. Undergraduate student. Regarding the question and answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3810673/422194).

If $S$ is a semi-group and for each $a \in S$, in the first part of the proof by contradiction: If $n>m$ and $a^n=a^m$ for any positive integers $n$ and $m$, how does this imply that $a^{n-(m-1)}\cdot a^{m-1} = a\cdot a^{m-1}$. I'm struggling to understand how one gets to this equation from $a^n=a^m$? Do you first multiply on the left and right with something?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: $a^{n-(m-1)}\cdot a^{m-1} = a^n$ and $a \cdot a^{m-1} = a^m$.

Comment: Should edit the question to note (as stated in your link) that $S$ has both cancellation laws.  It's a courtesy to readers to make the question as self-contained as possible.

Comment: @RobertShore The fact that $S$ is cancellative is totally irrelevant for this question. I rolled back to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^k=\underbrace{a·a·\ldots·a}_\text{$k$ times}$ so

$a^{n-(m-1)}a^{m-1}=\big(\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$n-(m-1)$ times}\big)\big(\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$m-1$ times}\big)=\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$n-(m-1)$ times}·\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$m-1$ times}=\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$n-(m-1)+(m-1)$ times}=\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$n-(m-1)+(m-1)$ times}=\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$n$ times}=a^n$

by associativity.

On the other hand, $a·a^{m-1}=a·\big(\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$m-1$ times}\big)=a·\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$m-1$ times}=\underbrace{a·\ldots·a}_\text{$m$ times}=a^m$

by associativity too.

Since $a^n=a^m$, we have the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're just regrouping the $a$'s that you already have.  Multiply the left-hand side by adding the exponents and you'll see that you have $a^n$ because $n-(m-1)+(m-1)=n$.  Similarly, multiply the right-hand side by adding exponents and you'll see that you have $a^m$ because $m=1+(m-1)$.  You need $n \gt m$ to be sure that all exponents in sight are positive.

Then using the cancellation law you have $1 \cdot a = a = a^{n-(m-1)}=a^{(n-m)+1}=a^{n-m}a$ and using the cancellation law again you see $a^{n-m}=1$.